# Replace "Refresh Icon" of SwipeRefreshLayout with text

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

It is possible with SwipeRefreshLayout to replace the "Refresh icon" with text?
Just like Twitter does:
[image]

Or it is possible to remove the icon? When the user swipes down, the "Refresh icon" i want to be invisible.

Comment: try this link [this link](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/05/android-swipe-down-to-refresh-listview-tutorial/)

Comment: this is just a simple SwipeRefreshLayout with the default Icon. I want to hide that icon or replace it it another one or with a text

Answer (score 0):

This library might help you - https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh

Comment: Currently works with:
ListView
ExpandableListView
GridView
WebView
ScrollView
HorizontalScrollView
ViewPager.
I want into a RecyclerView..

Comment: RecyclerView is just improved version of ListView. So i guess it will work for RecyclerView